# Problem with loading my front end local host due to metamask

Tags: metamask, ganache

I have been trying this Dapp university tutorial online and after following it meticulously I've come across this problem. I suspect it's metamask as the video said if I get this loading message I need to "trouble shoot" metamask. I have linked my ganache account to metamask using a private key and it has linked perfectly. I have no idea why my client side wont load.[image] [image: The local host front end does not load]

Comment: Hi, you have to add the front end code that you suspect is causing the problem if you want someone to help you. reading this question we cannot guess what is your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect part of the problem might be that the tutorial is dated before the major security change that made metamask require to ask for accounts. If the tutorial was created before November 6th, then you likely have this problem. I believe that the 2019 update should work, https://github.com/dappuniversity/election/tree/2019_update.

https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8